# Why second HttpClient.PostAsync returns 500?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

In the following code I receive 200 in the first request and 500 for all after that. I am new to `.Net Core C#` so I learned I should assign certain HttpClient attributes only once i.e. timeout.

However, my automated tests are successful first time but 500 after that. I am using HttpClientFactory.

```
if (httpClient.Timeout == null)
{
    httpClient.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Foo.timeout);
}

if (httpClient.BaseAddress == null) {
     httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(Foo.url);
}
response = await httpClient.PostAsync("", content);
```

Comment: HTTP 500 indicates a **server-side** error. It isn't your code, it's a bug in the server-side code. If it was a client-side error you'd get a HTTP 400-499 status code.

Comment: Btw, server-side error can be caused by incorrect request that server can't handle. Anyway, it's not an `HttpClient`-side issue.

Answer (score 2):

I found the issue with the code. I should have created a new instance of the HttpClient using the HttpClientFactory for every Http request:

```
_httpClient = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient(command.ClientId);
```

```
public class Foo
    {
        private readonly IHttpClientFactory _httpClientFactory;
        public Foo(IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory)
        {
            _httpClientFactory = httpClientFactory;
        }
        public async Task<HttpRequestMessage> Bar()
        {
            var httpClient = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient("Foo");
            using var response = await httpClient.PostAsync("example.com", new StringContent("Foo"));
            return response.RequestMessage;
            // here as there is no more reference to the _httpclient, the garbage 
            //collector will clean
            // up the _httpclient and release that instance. Next time the method is 
            //called a new
            // instance of the _httpclient is created
        }

    }
```

Comment: @upvoters Why pseudo-code is upvoted here? How can it help other members to solve their issues?

Comment: @aepot The posted code isn't psuedocode at all. What are you talking about?

Comment: `public  httpresponse Bar ()` the code you posted wouldn't compile at all.

Comment: @aepot The posted code is valid C# 8.0 that compiles in Visual Studio 2019 and Linqpad 6.

Comment: 1) What is `httpresponse` in `public  httpresponse Bar ()`? 2) `return response;` will cause `.Dispose()` of the returning `response` immediately (`using` statement). Thus you're returning a disposed object. 3) `collector will clean` will not compile 4) `called a new` will not compile. - this is not compilable pseudo-code.